# Use stdlib functions without including stdlib.h

Tags: c++, compilation, std

I am compiling a large number of files which use srand() and rand() without including stdlib.h. 
I'm aware that this is bad practice but, as I cannot change the files that I am compiling, inserting the necessary include statement in each file is not an option.

How can I configure my compiler to allow implicit inclusion of stdlib functions? Also, is there a way to implicitly use the std namespace in the same way?

Edit: Using g++

Edit: Looks like this is the answer (to the first part, at least). To compile a file as if stdlib.h is included, use the option -include stdlib.h

Comment: You could declare them yourself, though I don't see why you would.

Comment: I'm confused. You're **compiling** the files, but can't **change** them? If so, what's the issue? You're not responsible for the code, so it doesn't matter whether something is a "bad practice". Just compile them. If they don't compile, bounce them back to someone who **can** change them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've now mentioned that you're using GCC, you can just use the [`-include`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-include-978) flag.  Other compilers probably have equivalents.

---

If you don't have such a flag for your compiler, you could use the following not-entirely-serious solution, that should work nevertheless:

**nice.cc**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "naughty.cc"
```

(where naughty.cc is the original source file).

Of course, with a suitable build system, you could automatically generate the nice wrapper files.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already embracing bad practice, how about:

```
cat > foo.c << EOF
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "file-to-compile.c"
EOF

${CC} foo.c
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using GCC, so you can use the `-include` option (from [the manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)):

> Process file as if #include "file" appeared as the first line of the primary source file.

For example:

```
g++ -include stdlib.h foo.c
```